# How to secure remote access to admin/cms end?

Tags: security, configuration, browser, remote-access

What would be the best way to setup a secure remote access to ADMIN end/CMS of your web. app? - what available tools? configs? ideas? isolating admin end? there is talk of using SSL certs(how?)
Will be using browser on my PC to access Admin end to manage users..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would run the admin console only on the server’s localhost and use SSH to forward `localhost:1234` from the server’s point of view to `localhost:5678` from my machine’s point of view with the following:

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:5678:127.0.0.1:1234 user@server
```

Then you can access the forwarded port via `http://localhost:5678/`.